# Uma função rodar infinitamente no Servlet

Tags: java, aplicação-web, servlet

Eu tenho uma aplicação servlet que recebe constantemente requisições POST, eu faço o tratamento dos dados e o processamento normalmente nas suas devidas classes Java, porém uma das minhas aplicações ela não deve ser rodada quando houver uma requisição e sim a cada um período de tempo definido (ex: 1 hora).

Ou seja, independente de houver ou não chamadas no servlet, a cada um período de tempo essa função deve ser chamada e seu código executado.

Como isso seria feito numa aplicação Java Web Servlet?

Comment: Você pode agendar execução (procure por "`schedule`"). No Spring-boot, existe a anotação `@Schedule` (ou coisa assim) que você pode por em um método que ele será executado conforme estiver configurado na anotação. Sem necessidade de requisição externa nem para começar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um `ServletContextListener` em conjunto com um `ScheduledExecutorService`. O `ServletContextListener` vai ser chamado quando sua aplicação for inicializada e finalizada. O `ScheduledExecutorService` vai executar tarefas repetidamente.

### Executando algo quando a aplicação é inicializada:

Crie um listener:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ExampleContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Contexto inicializado!");
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Contexto destruido!");
  }
}
```

Para o listener ser reconhecido você pode usar o `web.xml`:

```
<listener>  
    <listener-class>
        com.example.ExampleContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Ou usar a anotação `@WebListener`:

```
@WebListener
public class ExampleContextListener implements ServletContextListener {  
    // ...
}
```

[Este artigo](http://www.deadcoderising.com/execute-code-on-webapp-startup-and-shutdown-using-servletcontextlistener/) e o próprio [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) explicam o funcionamento do `ServletContextListener`.

### Executar tarefas periodicamente:

Crie um `ScheduledExecutorService` e agende tarefas com um intervalo:

```
public void scheduleMyTask() {
  ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
  };

  ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTask, 1, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Neste exemplo, o `Runnable` myTask será executado a cada 2 minutos, com um delay inicial de 1 minuto. Ou seja, após 1 minuto desse bloco ser executado, será exibida a mensagem `Hello world` no console a cada dois minutos.

Você deve analisar se o método que atende melhor seu caso de uso é o `scheduleAtFixedRate` ou `scheduleWithFixedDelay`. A diferença entre eles é:

- `scheduleAtFixedRate` executa "sempre" no intervalo indicado.
- `scheduleWithFixedDelay` vai executar após o término da última execução + o intervalo

[Este artigo](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html) e o [próprio Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) explicam o funcionamento do `ScheduledExecutorService`.

### Juntando tudo:

Agora é só juntar os dois conceitos e agendar tarefas assim que a aplicação for inicializada:

```
@WebListener
public class ExampleContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    scheduleMyTask();
  }

  public void scheduleMyTask() {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
      }
    };

    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(myTask, 1, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  //...
}
```

---

Observação: alguns frameworks podem oferecer mecanismos próprios para isso. O ideal é ler sua documentação, caso venha a utilizá-los.